# Angular Reactive Forms validação ao clicar no botão

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validação, reactive-programming

Olá, estou tentando criar uma validação para verificar se já existe um cpf no banco de dados (ficticio), só que eu queria mudar o **gatilho**, ao invés de disparar a validação no **keyup** do campo, eu adicionei um **botao** ao lado do campo e ao clicar no botão gostaria que a validação fosse realizada e marcar o campo com vermelho se tiver o usuario ou marcar verde se nao tiver.

Obs: Estou usando stepper do angular material com um form para cada step, mas para o exemplo aqui irei mostrar somente 1 form com 1 campo que é o que quero validar.

Basicamente o codigo ficou o seguinte:

**component.ts**

```
this.cpfForm = this._formBuilder.group(
      {
        cpf: ['', Validators.required, [this.verificarCPF.bind(this)]]
      }
    );

verificarCPF(form: FormControl) {

    return this.signatureService.getUsersbyKey(form.value)
      .pipe(
        map( cpfExiste => cpfExiste ? { exists: true } : null)
      );
  }
```

**signature.service.ts**

```
getUsersbyKey(cpf: string) {
    return this.http.get('assets/dbteste/usuarios.json')
      .pipe(
        map((dados: { usuarios: any[] }) => dados.usuarios),
        // tap(console.log),
        map((dados: { cpf: string }[]) => dados.filter(x => x.cpf === cpf)),
        map((dados: any[]) => dados.length > 0)  //retorna true ou false
        //tap(console.log)
      );
  }
```

**assets/dbteste/usuarios.json**

```
{
    "usuarios": [{
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "renan",
            "email": "renan@renan.com",
            "cpf": "08368"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "renan2",
            "email": "renan2@renan.com",
            "cpf": "08369"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "nome": "renan3",
            "email": "renan3@renan.com",
            "cpf": "08360"
        }
    ]
}
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [@.disabled]="true" #stepper>
    <mat-step label="Informações Pessoais" [stepControl]="cpfForm">
      <form [formGroup]="cpfForm">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>CPF</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="CPF " formControlName="cpf" #cpf>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button 
  matTooltip="Verificar se ja existe  o CPF informado" 
  (click)="verificarCPF(cpf.value)" 
  class="ml-2 w-25" mat-raised-button color="primary">Verificar CPF </button>
        <div 
  *ngIf="cpfForm.get('cpf').hasError('exists') && cpfForm.get('cpf').touched" 
  class="invalid-feedback">
          CPF JA CADASTRADO!
        </div>

        <div>
          <button mat-button matStepperNext> Proximo </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-step>

... mais steps e formularios
```

E o resultado disso tudo é, uma validação a cada numero digitado

[image: https://pasteboard.co/J8G7WaC.png]

**::::[[UPDATE]]::::**

consegui setar o erro manualmente acho que de maneira nao ortodoxa (), mas agora surgiu outro problema,  o campo fica com o foco no botao, e para atualizar o status de erro no campo, tenho que clicar no input novamente :(

component.ts

```
verificarCPF() {
const valor = this.cpfForm.get('cpf').value;
console.log(valor);
return this.signatureService.getUsersbyKey(valor)
  .pipe(
    map(cpfExiste => cpfExiste ? this.cpfForm.controls['cpf'].setErrors({'exists': true}) : null),
  ).subscribe();
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu algum erro?

Comment: nop, nao esta dando erro

Comment: Tenta substituir isso `Validators.required, [this.verificarCPF.bind(this)]` por isso `[Validators.required]`. Aí na função `verificarCPF(form: FormControl) {` muda para essa aqui `verificarCPF(value: any) `, ai no envio para o `getUsersbyKey` envia assim `getUsersbyKey(value)`

Comment: Outra forma de pegar o valor pode ser assim. Você fez assim: `const valor = this.cpfForm.get('cpf').value;` pode ser assim também: `const valor = this.cpfForm.value.cpf;`

Comment: nao resolve :( olha o update que eu postei ai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para quem quiser ver a solução, segue o link no stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/renanduart3angular-validacao-botao?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts